# Как сделать такой ховер?

Tags: css, css3

[image: Ховер]

Как сделать такой ховер?
самая непонятная часть - это реализация поведения черного блока при снятии ховера

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю, что на чистом css такое вряд ли возможно. Вот вариант css-animation + jquery:

```js
$('.block').hover(function(){ 
  $('.fon').addClass('grow').removeClass('reduce');
}, function(){
  $('.fon').addClass('reduce').removeClass('grow');
});
```

```css
.block {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 30px;
  position: relative;
}
.fon {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
@keyframes grow {
  0% { width: 0; height: 0; }
  50% { width: 50%; height: 25%; }
  100% { width: 100%; height: 100% }
}
@keyframes reduce {
  0% { width: 100%; height: 100%; }
  50% { width: 50%; height: 75%; }
  100% { width: 0; height: 0 }
}
.fon.grow {
  animation: grow 0.3s linear forwards;
}
.fon.reduce {
  animation: reduce 0.3s linear forwards;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: auto;
  bottom: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block">
  <div class="fon"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!